# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollTop') Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have migrated MUI-4 to MUI-5 and facing this error.
Any Help?

Answer (score 23):

I discovered that I was feeding my own component inside the SnackBar. When I wrapped the content of SnackBar in a div, it was fixed. As the error message says "Expected an element that can hold a ref," SnackBar's child needs to be an element that can hold a ref, e.g. a div.

Before:
`<SnackBar> <MyAlert/> </SnackBar>`

After: `<SnackBar><div> <MyAlert/> </div> </SnackBar>`

Thanks

Comment: Absolutely bang on. Thank you.